# Chat-Ops Setup and suggestions

Tags: jenkins, slack, chatops

I have an idea which I'd like to implement. I want to make the best use of Chat-ops. Below are the requirement which I want to achieve:

1. I am planning to have a common chatroom, which would be specially
   made for deployments via Jenkins. I will be having a specific format
   of  the instruction on slack (something like deploy APP A onto QA
   environment). The chat bot  should then go find the jenkins  job for
   me and then trigger the jenkins build  for me.
2. When the Jenkins build  is triggered, Id like to find out the build  status, the job console, the  test results of the corresponding build.

I read a few blogs about chatops, but I am currently not aware of which set of tools to use to get this smooth. I was planning to use Slack+Hubot.

Any suggestions and comments on the above use cases?

Comment: StackStorm looks nice

Comment: @stephenking thanks....I was trying to integrate slack with Hubot....not sure if this would help

Comment: You may also want to look into just using [slash commands](https://api.slack.com/slash-commands) for your app.

Comment: We used mattermost with `slash commands` to execute a script, which can use the `REST API` to run a jenkins job. When the jenkins job is complete, there is a plugin that it can report in a chat channel.